# How do I disable Visual Studio debugger "safeguards"?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

During my classes, I sometimes run into the issue of my code working locally through Visual Studio but not through the auto-grader.  Normally, it seems to boil down to things like VS initializing variables I forgot to, things that the grader is not doing.  I've tried to find a list of all the things like that that VS does behind the scenes and whether or not I can disable them, but I haven't had much luck.  It could be because I don't know the actual terminology for what these safeguards are called, but so far, Google hasn't pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compile and run your code in Release mode, this should get rid of every "safeguard".

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've only been using VS educationally so I've never switched the mode.  After setting "Debug" to "Release", I rebuild and click "Start Without Debugging".  Is there anything more to it than that?

Comment: @dylosaur hopefully this should make your program run similar to its behaviour in the grading system (whatever that is). Of course, it's possible that your program fails on the tasks used for grading, not because of "safeguards" but due to the bugs you didn't detect with your test cases.

Comment: It was, probably predictably, just a bug I didn't account for, but I'm still happy to figure out how to switch between debug and release mode.  Thanks for the help.